# call by name and value clarification

Tags: scala

In Scala, does the following expression takes same number of steps, irrespective if you compute it by name or value?

The [coursera scala lecture1.2](https://class.coursera.org/progfun-003/lecture/3) - Elements of Programming - says both should take the same # of steps, where as i am getting one extra step in Call by Name as shown below:

```
def test(x  : Int, y : Int)  = x *x
```

expression: `test(2+3, 3*4)`

**Call By Value: (3 steps)**:

```
test(5, 12)

5*5

25
```

**Call By Name: (4 steps)**:

```
(2+3) * (2+3)

5 * (2+3)

5 * 5

25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget that in the call-by-value case the values need to be computed before the function is called:

```
// call-by-value
test(2+3, 3*4)
test(5, 3*4)
test(5, 12)
5*5
25

// call-by-name
test(2+3, 3*4)
(2+3)*(2+3)
5*(2+3)
5*5
25
```